# Mean equations of species in a compartment-based diffusion model

Tags: stochastic-processes

Reading the [Stochastic Modelling of Biological Processes Lecture Notes](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/1914) on modelling diffusion as a chain of chemical reactions (in Section 10.2, page 45), I'm struggling to flesh out the details left to the reader of multiplying the chemical master equation by $n_i$ and summing over all possible $n$ to establish a system of ODEs for the mean equations.

My issue seems to be that because the sum is over $R^K$, I always get every term cancelling, and can't find terms that survive. Any help understanding would be greatly appreciated!